# xConnect install: Property "errorMessages" cannot be found on this object

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, xconnect

I'm trying to install the XP0 local development version of Sitecore using George Chang's blog as a reference: https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2017/10/how-to-install-sitecore-9-with-the-sitecore-install-framework. I saved the Sitecore Install Framework downloads to one PS1 file, and the XP0 install scripts to a second file.

I had to increase the Solr start timeout to get past a checking error (from 8000 to 20000) but everything else was working until I got to this point in the xConnect XP0 install. From the xconnect-xp0 log file:

```
TerminatingError(Invoke-ManageSolrSchemaTask): "The running command stopped 
because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set 
to Stop: The property 'errorMessages' cannot be found on this object. 
Verify that the property exists."
```

Right before that error hit, this was the logged content (to provide context to which step it's failing at):

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Invoke-ManageSolrSchemaTask -Address https://localhost:8983/solr -Core sc90_xdb" on target "https://localhost:8983/solr".
[ConfigureSolrSchemas [1]]:[Schema] Modifying Schema on https://localhost:8983/solr : sc90_xdb
VERBOSE: Updating Solr Schema: Uri => 'https://localhost:8983/solr/sc90_xdb/schema?wt=json'
VERBOSE: POST https://localhost:8983/solr/sc90_xdb/schema?wt=json with -1-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 184-byte response of content type text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

This has happened a couple of times, so I'm not sure what the sticking point is. Solr is running just fine, and at the point of failure I see the two sc90_xdb cores (main and rebuild).

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using?  It'll need to be 6.2.2

Comment: 6.2.2 or 6.6.2? I've got 6.6.2 (originally 6.6.1 but someone said there was an issue with that one, but I thought 6.6.1 was announced as "should use" during Symposium). Using Windows 2016 Server SP1, SQL 2016 SP1 as well.

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part. 6.6.2 would be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll have to test this locally, but it could be a change in the response from Solr in 6.6.2 compared to 6.6.1.  It's looking for `errorMessages` to check if there were errors when calling solr and actually failing as the member does not exist.

As a temporary measure, you can tell SIF to continue on error by adding the following to the parameters for the task

`"ErrorAction": "Continue"`

This will enable SIF to continue processing when this task throws an error.

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for your test result, but meantime I'll give the ErrorAction bit a go. Thanks.